# calling angular component function from plain javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, web-bluetooth

I am using angular for my web app and i need bluetooth on one of my pages.
I am using loginov-rocks/bluetooth-terminal(https://github.com/loginov-rocks/bluetooth-terminal) for the bluetooth connection and it works i can conect my device and see data from it. now the problem i have is i cannot get the data from my recieve function to my angular component, i can print data to console, but that is not what i want, i want to parse my data and set some variables in my angular component from it.Here is my code:

```
let bluetooth = new BluetoothTerminal();

bluetooth.receive = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    //i want to call ParseBtData here from my angular component to parse data
    //or somehow send data and cach it for parsing inside my component
};

export class GpsAppComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit
{
//all the angular stuff

    parseBtData(data) {
        //parse my BT data and set some variables inside my component...
    };
}
```

I have tryed making BluetoothTerminal inside the component, but i still cannot call any function to parse my data. Is it even possible to do that, or is there another way i should aproach my problem?

Comment: just sharing thought for workaround, create some global object or variable and assign the value to it.

Comment: you should try to bind your context (bind `this` to your bluetooth receive function), with that you should be able to call function thats in your component's class. And put your bluetooth.receive inside your class, in its constructor for example. Here's some example to do so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: The problem is that you use a function outside the update cycle of angular, basically angular does not know anything that is not within its ecosystem, you must create a service and that service must be called from your component.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by moving my bluetooth inside the component and doing:

```
this.bluetooth.receive = (data) => {
        //console.log(data);
        this.writeToTerminalConsole(data);
    };
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the `receive` function's documentation for putting in this answer? I tried searching the Angular docs and it's not really finding anything about this.

Answer (score -1):

In general if you create an object javascript you can do it using declare, then the only is override the "received" data. But a change because an event not controlle by Angular, you need say to Angular that "something" has changed outside Angular, so you need use ngZone, some like:

```
//DISCLAMER: I don't know if work

declare var bluetooth = new BluetoothTerminal();

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit
{
   constructor(private ngZone:NgZone,private dataService:DataService){}
   ngAfterViewInit(){
       bluetooth.receive = (data)=> {
           this.ngZone.run(()=>{
              this.dataService.sendData(data)
           })
       };
   }
}
```

Then you only need define in your service

```
bluethoodData:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>()
sendData(data:any)
{
   this.bluethoodData.next(data)
}
```

And you can subscribe in any component to dataService.bluethoodData

```
   this.dataService.bluethoodData.subscribe(res=>{
       console.log(res)
   })
```

Comment: If you don't know whether it works, it's not an answer, it's a guess. Please verify your answer works, and if it doesn't, consider deleting it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, sorry, it's impossible know if really works unless I use a bluetooth connection, install the library and make a test. I have no bluetooth connection, so I only can imagine that the way to do it it's using ngZone.run because it's a "similar problem" with another interfaces or calls from javaScript. If someone can check and not work, as I don't like delete the answer, I'll edit it and strike it